NHibernate Delete from IQueryable with .Take
When trying to delete records in chunks from an IQueryable like this
session.Query<CityEntity>().Where(x => x.PostalCode.StartsWith("5")).Take(100).Delete() I get this exception:

Sequence contains no elements
at System.Linq.ThrowHelper.ThrowNoElementsException()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable1 source) at NHibernate.Linq.IntermediateHqlTree.ExecuteAddTakeClause(HqlExpression toTake) at NHibernate.Linq.IntermediateHqlTree.AddPendingHqlClausesToRoot() at NHibernate.Linq.IntermediateHqlTree.GetTranslation() at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.QueryModelVisitor.GenerateHqlQuery(QueryModel queryModel, VisitorParameters parameters, Boolean root, Nullable1 rootReturnType)
at NHibernate.Linq.NhLinqExpression.Translate(ISessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory, Boolean filter)
at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.CreateQueryTranslators(IQueryExpression queryExpression, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary2 filters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory) at NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryExpressionPlan.CreateTranslators(IQueryExpression queryExpression, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
at NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryExpressionPlan..ctor(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow, IDictionary2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory) at NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryPlanCache.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow, IDictionary2 enabledFilters)
at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow)
at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.CreateQuery(IQueryExpression queryExpression)
at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.ExecuteDml[T](QueryMode queryMode, Expression expression)
at NHibernate.Linq.DmlExtensionMethods.Delete[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)

Deleting all at once without the Take works but i want to avoid Sql Server Lock Escalation.
This older question suggests it should be possible:
Deleting top 100 records from database via NHibernate using linq
Tested in NHibernate versions 5.6.0-dev.4903 and 5.5.2.
Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? Any pointers appreciated.
Edit: Here is the log
NHibernate.Linq|Expression (partially evaluated): value(NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryable`1[Fs.Ikaros.Core.Data.Domain.Entity.CourtDirectoryCityEntity]).Where(x => x.PostalCode.StartsWith("5")).Take(100)
NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryPlanCache|unable to locate HQL query plan in cache; generating (DELETE .Take[Fs.Ikaros.Core.Data.Domain.Entity.CourtDirectoryCityEntity, Fs.Ikaros.Core.Data, Version=2024.1.2001.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null](.Where[Fs.Ikaros.Core.Data.Domain.Entity.CourtDirectoryCityEntity, Fs.Ikaros.Core.Data, Version=2024.1.2001.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null](NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryable`1[Fs.Ikaros.Core.Data.Domain.Entity.CourtDirectoryCityEntity], Quote((x, ) => (x.PostalCode.StartsWith(p1, ))), ), p2, ))
In the meantime I found an old issue in NHibernates github
known but ignored issue from 2019

Can you enable the SQL query logging to get some insight into how that LINQ is being translated into SQL?

added debug level logging output in the question,
it seems the "var hqlQuery = _root.NodesPreOrder.OfType().First();"
just does not find any HqlQuery.

So it's an NH defect?
